# How can i use special glyphs in large font sizes, with fontspec?

Tags: symbols, fontspec, fontsize

now i have some trouble with font size declaration, using XeTeX's fontspec package. I read the fontspec manual. There is no explicit section about font size, but i see that the author of the manual using \fontsize{48}{48} command to declare the font size. It works for me also, e.g.:

```
\fontsize{60}{66}
\fontspec{Garamond Premier Pro}
Some text with font size 60 pt.\\
```

Or if Garamond is default, i can use:

```
\fontsize{60}{66}\selectfont
Some text with font size 60 pt.\\
```

That's fine, but if i want to use some special glyphs, for example fleurons in large font sizes, som ugly boxes appears in the pdf instead the character:

```
\fontsize{60}{66}\selectfont
Some text, and a fleuron: \symbol{\string"E1C0} or simply: \char"E1C0\\
```

I experimented, that the limit is between 14 and 15 pt: with 14 pt size, the fleuron appears, with 15 pt size and over, the box. What is the reason of this behaviour, and how can i scale these special glyphs larger than 14 pt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is that with the family "Garamond Premier Pro" different fonts are chosen at different sizes ("Display" for big sizes, for example) and the symbol is only in the "Text" size.

A workaround could be to define a font face for the fleurons:

```
\newfontface{\fleurons}[Path=/path/to/the/font/]{GaramondPremierPro-Regular.otf}
```

Substitute to `/path/to/the/font/` the actual path (this optional argument might be unnecessary, depending on where your font resides) and use the actual file name in the mandatory argument (it might be different from the name I concocted). Then

```
\fontsize{60}{72}\fleurons\symbol{\string"E1C0}
```

should use the "fixed" font.

Sorry for the many "do-it-yourself" in the answer, but I don't happen to own Garamond Premier Pro.

### Test file

I have managed to access the "Minion Pro" fonts and indeed **fontspec** defines different fonts for different sizes. You can see if my diagnosis is correct by compiling the following test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\begin{document}

\fontname\font

\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont
\fontname\font

\end{document}
```

The PDF file should show the names of the font used and they should be different.

Comment: It works fine. And all the information needed here, can be found in the manual, but i'm so beginner with fontspec, that i couldn't put it together. I compiled also your test file, and that's right, over 15 pt it uses the Display font, which doesn't have the ornaments. Thank You!

Comment: @vizipok: which pages in the fontspec manual deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you have another main font and I cannot see with fontforge that there is a fleuron symbol at that position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\Fleurons{Garamond Premier Pro}
\newcommand*\fleurons[1][{60}{66}]{{\Fleurons%
   \fontsize#1\selectfont\symbol{\string"E1C0}}}

\begin{document}

\fleurons
\fleurons[{80}{90}]

\end{document}
```

There is also a free font `Fleurons.ttf` available