# How can I make XeLaTeX use "display", "subhead", and "caption" varieties of a font when appropriate?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am using Adobe's Garamond Premier Pro and it has various varities for use with larger and smaller forms of text (see http://www.adobe.com/type/topics/opticalsize.html).

Is there a good way to make XeLaTeX use the proper face at the proper time (e.g., footnotes should be in caption, etc). Of course, some care must be taken that things like `\emph` properly work in the context.

Comment: Yes. It's described in the fontspec manual.

Comment: The optical sizes are selected automatically; see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22777/how-can-i-use-special-glyphs-in-large-font-sizes-with-fontspec)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working…

Answer (score 4):

The [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/) package allows you to tailor font variants by size.

Here's how I do it for Minion Pro; you'll need to adapt it for your case:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
...
\setmainfont[%
    Numbers=OldStyle,
    Kerning=Uppercase,
    SizeFeatures={%
        {Size={-8.4},Font=* Caption},
        {Size={8.41-13.0},Font=*},
        {Size={13.01-19.9},Font=* Subhead},
        {Size={19.91-},Font=* Display}
    }
]{Minion Pro}
```

What this says is: "For sizes up to 8.4pt, use Minion Pro Caption; up to 13.0 use Minion Pro; up to 19.9 Minion Pro Subhead; and Minion Pro Display above that".