# TeXLive2016 lualatex does not use optical sizes for MinionPro opentype font

Tags: luatex, fontspec, luaotfload, texlive-2016

With current texlive 2016, the file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}%
\newcommand{\MyText}{No offence meant, I even upvoted your answer.}

\verb|\tiny|=\tiny\MyText\par
\verb|\scriptsize|=\scriptsize\MyText\par
\verb|\footnotesize|=\footnotesize\MyText\par
\verb|\normalsize|=\normalsize\MyText\par
\verb|\large|=\large\MyText\par
\verb|\Large|=\Large\MyText\par
\verb|\LARGE|=\LARGE\MyText\par
\verb|\huge|=\huge\MyText\par
\verb|\Huge|=\Huge\MyText\par

\end{document}
```

results in a PDF that makes use of LMMono8, -10, and -12, but from the MinionPro Opticals, only MinionPro-Regular is used. Switching back to
TeXLive-2015 results in a file with MinionPro-Regular, -Capt, -Subh, and -Disp, as expected.

Any hint on how to restore automatic selection of proper optical 
sizes for opentype fonts?

Comment: What are »Capt«, »Subh« and »Disp«? Why do you expect their usage, even when simply changing the size of the letters?

Comment: Caption, Subhead and Display are terms used to discern fonts designed for different sizes. The legibility of text printed in very small sizes, say, 6pt, is increased in a Caption font designed for small sizes, while the intricacy and beauty of the glyphs come to their full beauty in fonts designed for larger sizes, say, 20pt. An example waits at [link](https://cfce3.dyndns.org/w.pdf)

Comment: As it seems, you can have this feature with pdftex as well: This website https://recordnotfound.com/FontPro-sebschub-107127 explains, how to setup Minion Pro etc. for pdftex and says: »Furthermore, the optical sizes Caption, Text, Subhead and Display are supported...« OK, this does not solve your issue, however, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Does it work for you with the solution described here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46685/4736 ?

Comment: There are a lot of similar issues recently. This is due to some issues with luaotfload. For example, see https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/363, which is an issue I opened recently. I showed an example of working around the issue with Cronos Pro. The same method will work for Minion as well. I think luaotfload will fix these issues in the near future.

Comment: @Keks Dose: Using  the optional parameters described in tex.stackexchange.com/a/46685/4736  results in a correct PDF file. If, however, bold or italics is used, the bold and italics parts are set in the MinionPro-Capt font (bold or It, respectively) in all sizes. That is, the selection does not work for combinations. Maybe a full definition of all combinations could be given in the optional parameter to \setmainfont, but before, things worked out automagically, like a charm ...

Comment: It works with manual selection `\setmainfont[SizeFeatures={{Size={-8.4},Font=* Capt},{Size={8.4-13},Font=*},{Size={13-19.9},Font=* Subh},{Size={19.9-},Font=* Disp}}]{Minion Pro}`  I admit it is not as convenient as automatic selection, but definitely a viable workaround for the time until a fix is released.  For me it actually sufficed to typeset with manual selection once.  From then on LuaTeX remembered the optical sizes.

Comment: Manual selection works partially: As soon as a mix of regular and other weights and italics are used, things turn out to be quite tricky. I have returned to TeXlive 2015 for work on a booklet printed in A6 format - lots of fonts selected automagically. IMHO, this is a major regression that needs a fix. I learned the new code is much faster - if at all possible, I'd prefer a rollback to the old code which did a marvellous job if the new code can't be fixed. Admittedly, the font naming schemes are a mess. I'd be happy to rename the OTF files if only I knew the naming scheme the code needs ...

Comment: However, saying it needs a fix here isn't speaking to the right people ;). I think the LuaTeX folks are well aware this needs a fix. There have been quite a lot of changes, as I understand it. LuaTeX is, after all, still in development and somewhat experimental, even though it is usable for many purposes. A publisher wouldn't use LuaTeX yet, for example, as it would make their production process liable to breakage. If you need more stability, you need to stick to (pdf)TeX. (Even then, I wouldn't update just before a critical deadline!)

Comment: What I mean is, that I don't know the details but rolling back is not necessarily an option, depending on what's involved and how this is connected to other changes and so on. You can't always reverse changes to one part of the code in isolation ....

Comment: I have given an answer to another question http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315479/5895 it shall solve your problem as well

Answer (score 5):

Section 8.6 of the fontspec manual says:

> [...] OpenType fonts with optical scaling will exist in several discrete
>   sizes, and these will be selected by XETEX and LuaTEX ***automatically***
>   determined by the current font size [...]

But it can only do so, if it gets the information it needs to make this automatical selection. What information does it need? The fontspec manual only gives an indrect hint in the next paragraph by specifing how it expects the information to be provided:

> The SizeFeatures feature (Section 7.6 on page 17) can be
>   used to specify exactly which optical sizes will be used for ranges
>   of font size. [...]

Fontspec needs the *design sizes* of the fonts. As the name says this size is determined by the font designer. Unfortunately the otf file format does not contain this information. If you buy the fonts they usually come with a readme file. In case of Minion Pro this readme file has a section on optical sizes. There a little table can be found, that provides the need information.

> Caption: from 6.0 to 8.4 points
>
> Body Text: from 8.4 to 13.0 points
>
> Subhead: from 13.0 to 19.9 points
>
> Display: from 19.9 to 72.0 points

This table is likely to be different for every font, because the respective font designer made different choices.

As already mentioned in the comments you now can change

```
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
```

which is not enough, too

```
\setmainfont{minionpro-}[
Extension={.otf},
UprightFont={*regular},
ItalicFont={*it},
BoldFont={*bold},
BoldItalicFont={*boldit},
Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},
SizeFeatures={
    {Size={-8.4},Font=*capt},
    {Size={8.4-13.0}},
    {Size={13.0-19.9},Font=*subh},
    {Size={19.91-},Font=*disp}
}]
```

This is of course dependant on the naming conventions of the otf files. As there is no standard that I am aware of you probably have to adjust them. The otf files on my computer are all in lower case thus I have file names like:

```
minionpro-capt.otf
minionpro-regular.otf
minionpro-subh.otf
minionpro-disp.otf
```

for the upright fonts, for the italics ones I have

```
minionpro-itcapt.otf
minionpro-it.otf
minionpro-itsubh.otf
minionpro-itdisp.otf
```

and so on

```
minionpro-boldcapt.otf
minionpro-bold.otf
minionpro-boldsubh.otf
minionpro-bolddisp.otf
```

Minion Pro also comes with medium and semibold versions. Thus if the "normal" bold version is too bold, then one could replace them by changing

```
BoldFont={*bold},
BoldItalicFont={*boldit},
```

into

```
BoldFont={*medium},
BoldItalicFont={*mediumit},
```

fontspec also offers to work with the font names instead for the fonts file names. According to the fontspec manual section 7.6 page 22

> Interaction with other features For SizeFeatures to work with ItalicFeatures, BoldFeatures, etc., and SmallCapsFeatures, a strict heirarchy is required: [...]

I can get it to work by writing this:

```
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[
Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},
UprightFeatures={
  SizeFeatures={
    {Size={-8.4},Font=*Capt},
    {Size={8.4-13.0},Font=*Regular},
    {Size={13.0-19.9},Font=*Subh},
    {Size={19.9-},Font=*Disp}
}},
ItalicFeatures={
  SizeFeatures={
    {Size={-8.4},Font=*It Capt},
    {Size={8.4-13.0},Font=*It},
    {Size={13.0-19.9},Font=*It Subh},
    {Size={19.9-},Font=*It Disp}
}},
BoldFeatures={
  SizeFeatures={
    {Size={-8.4},Font=*Bold Capt},
    {Size={8.4-13.0},Font=*Bold},
    {Size={13.0-19.9},Font=*Bold Subh},
    {Size={19.9-},Font=*Bold Disp}
}},
BoldItalicFeatures={
  SizeFeatures={
    {Size={-8.4},Font=*Bold It Capt},
    {Size={8.4-13.0},Font=*Bold It Capt},
    {Size={13.0-19.9},Font=*Bold It Subh},
    {Size={19.9-},Font=*Bold It Disp}
}}]
```

Comment: The otf file format *does* contain the design sizes: see the output of `otfinfo -z *.otf` (run in the directory where you keep Minion Pro Opticals).

Answer (score 3):

Before `fontspec` is loaded the document class defines all font sizes, the reason why Latin Modern is used here as a default. However, after loading `fontspec` and using `\setmainfont` everything is redefined. Compare the output: in the left column there is Minion Pro and in the right Latin Modern.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\parindent=0pt
\newcommand\MyText{No offence meant, I even upvoted your answer.}
\newcommand\cs[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}

\begin{document}%

    \cs{tiny}=\tiny\MyText\par
    \cs{scriptsize}=\scriptsize\MyText\par
    \cs{footnotesize}=\footnotesize\MyText\par
    \cs{normalsize}=\normalsize\MyText\par
    \cs{large}=\large\MyText\par
    \cs{Large}=\Large\MyText\par
    \cs{LARGE}=\LARGE\MyText\par
    \cs{huge}=\huge\MyText\par
    \cs{Huge}=\Huge\MyText\par

\newpage\normalsize
\fontspec{Latin Modern Roman}
    \cs{tiny}=\tiny\MyText\par
    \cs{scriptsize}=\scriptsize\MyText\par
    \cs{footnotesize}=\footnotesize\MyText\par
    \cs{normalsize}=\normalsize\MyText\par
    \cs{large}=\large\MyText\par
    \cs{Large}=\Large\MyText\par
    \cs{LARGE}=\LARGE\MyText\par
    \cs{huge}=\huge\MyText\par
    \cs{Huge}=\Huge\MyText\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the

```
[...]
ZUQBJT+MinionPro-Capt-Identity-H     CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      9  0
GZICFI+MinionPro-Subh-Identity-H     CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     15  0
VLPSCX+MinionPro-Disp-Identity-H     CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     17  0
[...]
```

are used only by `xelatex`, if not defined via `fontspec`