# Minion Pro, TL2016 and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, minionpro, texlive-2016

When I compile with LuaLaTeX and TL2016 this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{shellesc}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}

\huge{huge}
\textbf{\huge{huge}}

\Huge{Huge}
\textbf{\Huge{Huge}}


\end{document}
```

I have this .pdf.

[image]

Any help? With TL2015 all is correct. Thanks

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a `luaotfload` issue. At any rate, using the instruction

```
\setmainfont[BoldFont={Minion Pro Bold}]{Minion Pro}
```

instead of

```
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
```

fixes the problem.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={Minion Pro Bold}]{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
\huge huge \textbf{huge} \Huge Huge \textbf{Huge}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, this MWE doesn't seem to require the `luatex85` and `shellesc` packages.

A separate matter: `\huge` and `\Huge` don't take arguments. Hence, don't write `\huge{huge}`; instead, write `{\huge huge}`.

Comment: `@Mico`Yes, this MWE doesn't required the `luatex85 and ... ` but to cut and paste is a problem.

Answer (score 6):

It is indeed an issue with `luatoftload` as Mico said. But unfortunately the fix is not as simple as he shows. Mico's answer will not help the font loader to properly use the correct optical sized fonts (MinionPro-BoldCapt, etc.). And at the moment there's no fix from the `fontspec` end. Instead, you will need to patch the name database generated by `luaotfload`. Below is my approach.

1. (Optional) Run `luaotfload-tool -u -f`
2. Copy `luaotfload-names.lua.gz` to your working directory. Mine can be found in `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names` since my `/usr/local`'s owner was changed. But most users will find it in the subdirectory of `~/.texlive`.
3. Apply the following patch, by `texlua patch-names.lua`, where `patch-names.lua`'s contents is attached at the end of this post. It will fix not only Minion Pro but also all other Optical sized fonts in Adobe Font Folio. You can delete fixes for fonts that you don't have.
4. Copy the generated `luaotfload-names-patched.lua.gz` and `luaotfload-names-patched.luc` to appropriate placed (e.g., `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names` in my case), remember to rename them to `luaotfload-names.lua.gz` and `luaotfload-names.luc` respectively. The reason I did not produce them with the original names was that I wanted to closely compare the generated files with the one I copied in step 2 first to make sure everything was all right.
5. Also you may want to delete `luaotfload-lookup-cache.lua` and `luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc`.

This approach is quite complicated at the moment. Someone knows `luaotfload`, `lua` and `kpse` better may find a more automated process than I described here.

The `patch-names.lua` file:

```
kpse.set_program_name 'luatex'

require 'lualibs'

names = load(gzip.load('luaotfload-names.lua.gz'), 't')()

-- Change "system" to "local" or "texmf" if needed.
families = names.families.system.otf
files = names.files.bare.system.otf

-- Arno Pro
families['arnopro'] = {
  b = {
    {  8,  8.5,  5.9, files['ArnoPro-BoldCaption'] },
    { 10,   11,  8.5, files['ArnoPro-BoldSmText'] },
    { 12,   14,   11, files['ArnoPro-Bold'] },
    { 18, 21.5,   14, files['ArnoPro-BoldSubhead'] },
    { 36,   72, 21.5, files['ArnoPro-BoldDisplay'] },
  },
  bi = {
    {  8,  8.5,  5.9, files['ArnoPro-BoldItalicCaption'] },
    { 10,   11,  8.5, files['ArnoPro-BoldItalicSmText'] },
    { 12,   14,   11, files['ArnoPro-BoldItalic'] },
    { 18, 21.5,   14, files['ArnoPro-BoldItalicSubhead'] },
    { 36,   72, 21.5, files['ArnoPro-BoldItalicDisplay'] },
  },
  i = {
    {  8,  8.5,  5.9, files['ArnoPro-ItalicCaption'] },
    { 10,   11,  8.5, files['ArnoPro-ItalicSmText'] },
    { 12,   14,   11, files['ArnoPro-Italic'] },
    { 18, 21.5,   14, files['ArnoPro-ItalicSubhead'] },
    { 36,   72, 21.5, files['ArnoPro-ItalicDisplay'] },
  },
  r = {
    {  8,  8.5,  5.9, files['ArnoPro-Caption'] },
    { 10,   11,  8.5, files['ArnoPro-SmText'] },
    { 12,   14,   11, files['ArnoPro-Regular'] },
    { 18, 21.5,   14, files['ArnoPro-Subhead'] },
    { 36,   72, 21.5, files['ArnoPro-Display'] },
  },
}

-- Brioso Pro
families['briosopro'] = {
  b = {
    {  8, 9.4,   6, files['BriosoPro-BoldCapt'] },
    { 11,  14, 9.4, files['BriosoPro-Bold'] },
    { 18,  21,  14, files['BriosoPro-BoldSubh'] },
    { 72,  72,  21, files['BriosoPro-BoldDisp'] },
  },
  bi = {
    {  8, 9.4,   6, files['BriosoPro-BoldItCapt'] },
    { 11,  14, 9.4, files['BriosoPro-BoldIt'] },
    { 18,  21,  14, files['BriosoPro-BoldItSubh'] },
    { 72,  72,  21, files['BriosoPro-BoldItDisp'] },
  },
  i = {
    {  8, 9.4,   6, files['BriosoPro-ItCapt'] },
    { 11,  14, 9.4, files['BriosoPro-Italic'] },
    { 18,  21,  14, files['BriosoPro-ItSubh'] },
    { 72,  72,  21, files['BriosoPro-ItDisp'] },
  },
  r = {
    {  8, 9.4,   6, files['BriosoPro-Capt'] },
    { 11,  14, 9.4, files['BriosoPro-Regular'] },
    { 18,  21,  14, files['BriosoPro-Subh'] },
    { 72,  72,  21, files['BriosoPro-Disp'] },
  },
}

-- Chaparral Pro
families['chaparralpro'] = {
  b = {
    {  8,  8.4,    1, files['ChaparralPro-BoldCapt'] },
    { 11, 12.9,  8.4, files['ChaparralPro-Bold'] },
    { 18, 25.9, 12.9, files['ChaparralPro-BoldSubh'] },
    { 72, 99.9, 25.9, files['ChaparralPro-BoldDisp'] },
  },
  bi = {
    {  8,  8.4,    1, files['ChaparralPro-BoldItCapt'] },
    { 11, 12.9,  8.4, files['ChaparralPro-BoldIt'] },
    { 18, 25.9, 12.9, files['ChaparralPro-BoldItSubh'] },
    { 72, 99.9, 25.9, files['ChaparralPro-BoldItDisp'] },
  },
  i = {
    {  8,  8.4,    1, files['ChaparralPro-ItCapt'] },
    { 11, 12.9,  8.4, files['ChaparralPro-Italic'] },
    { 18, 25.9, 12.9, files['ChaparralPro-ItSubh'] },
    { 72, 99.9, 25.9, files['ChaparralPro-ItDisp'] },
  },
  r = {
    {  8,  8.4,    1, files['ChaparralPro-Capt'] },
    { 11, 12.9,  8.4, files['ChaparralPro-Regular'] },
    { 18, 25.9, 12.9, files['ChaparralPro-Subh'] },
    { 72, 99.9, 25.9, files['ChaparralPro-Disp'] },
  },
}

-- Garamond Premier Pro
families['garamondpremierpro'] = {
  b = {
    {  8,  8.9,  5.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-BdCapt'] },
    { 11, 14.9,  8.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-Bd'] },
    { 18, 22.9, 14.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-BdSubh'] },
    { 36,   72, 22.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-BdDisp'] },
  },
  bi = {
    {  8,  8.9,  5.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-BdItCapt'] },
    { 11, 14.9,  8.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-BdIt'] },
    { 18, 22.9, 14.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-BdItSubh'] },
    { 36,   72, 22.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-BdItDisp'] },
  },
  i = {
    {  8,  8.9,  5.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-ItCapt'] },
    { 11, 14.9,  8.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-It'] },
    { 18, 22.9, 14.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-ItSubh'] },
    { 36,   72, 22.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-ItDisp'] },
  },
  r = {
    {  8,  8.9,  5.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-Capt'] },
    { 11, 14.9,  8.9, files['GaramondPremrPro'] },
    { 18, 22.9, 14.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-Subh'] },
    { 36,   72, 22.9, files['GaramondPremrPro-Disp'] },
  },
}

-- Adobe Jenson Pro
families['adobejensonpro'] = {
  b = {
    {  8,    9,    6, files['AJensonPro-BoldCapt'] },
    { 12, 13.4,    9, files['AJensonPro-Bold'] },
    { 19, 21.9, 13.4, files['AJensonPro-BoldSubh'] },
    { 72,   72, 21.9, files['AJensonPro-BoldDisp'] },
  },
  bi = {
    {  8,    9,    6, files['AJensonPro-BoldItCapt'] },
    { 12, 13.4,    9, files['AJensonPro-BoldIt'] },
    { 19, 21.9, 13.4, files['AJensonPro-BoldItSubh'] },
    { 72,   72, 21.9, files['AJensonPro-BoldItDisp'] },
  },
  i = {
    {  8,    9,    6, files['AJensonPro-ItCapt'] },
    { 12, 13.4,    9, files['AJensonPro-It'] },
    { 19, 21.9, 13.4, files['AJensonPro-ItSubh'] },
    { 72,   72, 21.9, files['AJensonPro-ItDisp'] },
  },
  r = {
    {  8,    9,    6, files['AJensonPro-Capt'] },
    { 12, 13.4,    9, files['AJensonPro-Regular'] },
    { 19, 21.9, 13.4, files['AJensonPro-Subh'] },
    { 72,   72, 21.9, files['AJensonPro-Disp'] },
  },
}

-- Kepler Std
families['keplerstd'] = {
  b = {
    {  8,  8.9,    6, files['KeplerStd-BoldCapt'] },
    { 11, 13.9,  8.9, files['KeplerStd-Bold'] },
    { 18,   23, 13.9, files['KeplerStd-BoldSubh'] },
    { 72,   72,   23, files['KeplerStd-BoldDisp'] },
  },
  bi = {
    {  8,  8.9,    6, files['KeplerStd-BoldItCapt'] },
    { 11, 13.9,  8.9, files['KeplerStd-BoldIt'] },
    { 18,   23, 13.9, files['KeplerStd-BoldItSubh'] },
    { 72,   72,   23, files['KeplerStd-BoldItDisp'] },
  },
  i = {
    {  8,  8.9,    6, files['KeplerStd-ItCapt'] },
    { 11, 13.9,  8.9, files['KeplerStd-Italic'] },
    { 18,   23, 13.9, files['KeplerStd-ItSubh'] },
    { 72,   72,   23, files['KeplerStd-ItDisp'] },
  },
  r = {
    {  8,  8.9,    6, files['KeplerStd-Capt'] },
    { 11, 13.9,  8.9, files['KeplerStd-Regular'] },
    { 18,   23, 13.9, files['KeplerStd-Subh'] },
    { 72,   72,   23, files['KeplerStd-Disp'] },
  },
}

-- Minion Pro
families['minionpro'] = {
  b = {
    {  8,  8.4,    6, files['MinionPro-BoldCapt'] },
    { 11,   13,  8.4, files['MinionPro-Bold'] },
    { 19, 19.9,   13, files['MinionPro-BoldSubh'] },
    { 72,   72, 19.9, files['MinionPro-BoldDisp'] },
  },
  bi = {
    {  8,  8.4,    6, files['MinionPro-BoldItCapt'] },
    { 11,   13,  8.4, files['MinionPro-BoldIt'] },
    { 19, 19.9,   13, files['MinionPro-BoldItSubh'] },
    { 72,   72, 19.9, files['MinionPro-BoldItDisp'] },
  },
  i = {
    {  8,  8.4,    6, files['MinionPro-ItCapt'] },
    { 11,   13,  8.4, files['MinionPro-It'] },
    { 19, 19.9,   13, files['MinionPro-ItSubh'] },
    { 72,   72, 19.9, files['MinionPro-ItDisp'] },
  },
  r = {
    {  8,  8.4,    6, files['MinionPro-Capt'] },
    { 11,   13,  8.4, files['MinionPro-Regular'] },
    { 19, 19.9,   13, files['MinionPro-Subh'] },
    { 72,   72, 19.9, files['MinionPro-Disp'] },
  },
}

-- Utopia Std
families['utopiastd'] = {
  b = {
    {  8, 8.9,   6, files['UtopiaStd-BoldCapt'] },
    { 11,  13, 8.9, files['UtopiaStd-Bold'] },
    { 18,  20,  13, files['UtopiaStd-BoldSubh'] },
    { 72,  72,  20, files['UtopiaStd-BoldDisp'] },
  },
  bi = {
    {  8, 8.9,   6, files['UtopiaStd-BoldCaptIt'] },
    { 11,  13, 8.9, files['UtopiaStd-BoldIt'] },
    { 18,  20,  13, files['UtopiaStd-BoldSubhIt'] },
    { 72,  72,  20, files['UtopiaStd-BoldDispIt'] },
  },
  i = {
    {  8, 8.9,   6, files['UtopiaStd-CaptIt'] },
    { 11,  13, 8.9, files['UtopiaStd-Italic'] },
    { 18,  20,  13, files['UtopiaStd-SubhIt'] },
    { 72,  72,  20, files['UtopiaStd-DispIt'] },
  },
  r = {
    {  8, 8.9,   6, files['UtopiaStd-Capt'] },
    { 11,  13, 8.9, files['UtopiaStd-Regular'] },
    { 18,  20,  13, files['UtopiaStd-Subh'] },
    { 72,  72,  20, files['UtopiaStd-Disp'] },
  },
}

-- Warnock
families['warnockpro'] = {
  b = {
    {  8,  8.9,    1, files['WarnockPro-BoldCapt'] },
    { 11, 12.9,  8.9, files['WarnockPro-Bold'] },
    { 18, 22.9, 12.9, files['WarnockPro-BoldSubh'] },
    { 72, 99.9, 22.9, files['WarnockPro-BoldDisp'] },
  },
  bi = {
    {  8,  8.9,    1, files['WarnockPro-BoldItCapt'] },
    { 11, 12.9,  8.9, files['WarnockPro-BoldIt'] },
    { 18, 22.9, 12.9, files['WarnockPro-BoldItSubh'] },
    { 72, 99.9, 22.9, files['WarnockPro-BoldItDisp'] },
  },
  i = {
    {  8,  8.9,    1, files['WarnockPro-ItCapt'] },
    { 11, 12.9,  8.9, files['WarnockPro-It'] },
    { 18, 22.9, 12.9, files['WarnockPro-ItSubh'] },
    { 72, 99.9, 22.9, files['WarnockPro-ItDisp'] },
  },
  r = {
    {  8,  8.9,    1, files['WarnockPro-Capt'] },
    { 11, 12.9,  8.9, files['WarnockPro-Regular'] },
    { 18, 22.9, 12.9, files['WarnockPro-Subh'] },
    { 72, 99.9, 22.9, files['WarnockPro-Disp'] },
  },
}

-- Cronos Pro
families['cronospro'] = {
  b = {
    {  8,  8,  6, files['CronosPro-BoldCapt'] },
    { 11, 14,  8, files['CronosPro-Bold'] },
    { 18, 24, 14, files['CronosPro-BoldSubh'] },
    { 72, 72, 24, files['CronosPro-BoldDisp'] },
  },
  bi = {
    {  8,  8,  6, files['CronosPro-BoldCaptIt'] },
    { 11, 14,  8, files['CronosPro-BoldIt'] },
    { 18, 24, 14, files['CronosPro-BoldSubhIt'] },
    { 72, 72, 24, files['CronosPro-BoldDispIt'] },
  },
  i = {
    {  8,  8,  6, files['CronosPro-CaptIt'] },
    { 11, 14,  8, files['CronosPro-Italic'] },
    { 18, 24, 14, files['CronosPro-SubhIt'] },
    { 72, 72, 24, files['CronosPro-DispIt'] },
  },
  r = {
    {  8,  8,  6, files['CronosPro-Capt'] },
    { 11, 14,  8, files['CronosPro-Regular'] },
    { 18, 24, 14, files['CronosPro-Subh'] },
    { 72, 72, 24, files['CronosPro-Disp'] },
  },
}

-- Sanvito Pro
-- Note that, Sanvito is a script font, which does not have a distinction between Upright and Italic. So I used the same style for both.
families['sanvitopro'] = {
  b = {
    {  8,  9.5,    6, files['SanvitoPro-BoldCapt'] },
    { 12,   15,  9.6, files['SanvitoPro-Bold'] },
    { 18, 22.9, 15.1, files['SanvitoPro-BoldSubh'] },
    { 72,   72,   23, files['SanvitoPro-BoldDisp'] },
  },
  bi = {
    {  8,  9.5,    6, files['SanvitoPro-BoldCapt'] },
    { 12,   15,  9.6, files['SanvitoPro-Bold'] },
    { 18, 22.9, 15.1, files['SanvitoPro-BoldSubh'] },
    { 72,   72,   23, files['SanvitoPro-BoldDisp'] },
  },
  i = {
    {  8,  9.5,    6, files['SanvitoPro-Capt'] },
    { 12,   15,  9.6, files['SanvitoPro-Regular'] },
    { 18, 22.9, 15.1, files['SanvitoPro-Subh'] },
    { 72,   72,   23, files['SanvitoPro-Disp'] },
  },
  r = {
    {  8,  9.5,    6, files['SanvitoPro-Capt'] },
    { 12,   15,  9.6, files['SanvitoPro-Regular'] },
    { 18, 22.9, 15.1, files['SanvitoPro-Subh'] },
    { 72,   72,   23, files['SanvitoPro-Disp'] },
  },
}

-- Myriad Pro. This can also be done with fontspec using BoldFont etc., and similarly for many other fonts with extensive ranges of weights and widths, which luaotfload will often get it wrong.
families['myriadpro'] = {
  b = {
    {11, 0, 0, files['MyriadPro-Bold']},
  },
  bi = {
    {11, 0, 0, files['MyriadPro-BoldIt']},
  },
  i = {
    {11, 0, 0, files['MyriadPro-It']},
  },
  r = {
    {11, 0, 0, files['MyriadPro-Regular']},
  },
}

data = table.serialize(names, true)
gzip.save('luaotfload-names-patched.lua.gz', data)
local f = io.open('luaotfload-names-patched.luc', 'wb')
local s = load(data)
f:write(string.dump(s, true))
f:close()
```

Comment: +1. Not having access to the optically-sized variants of the Adobe fonts, I had no inkling of this problem.

Comment: @Mico Nonetheless your help is very welcome. I myself had many questions answered by you. I think the patch can be improved. There's quite a few things that are hard coded into it which I don't like. But I don't know luatex well enough to do it otherwise without making it terribly tedious

Comment: `@Yan Zhou` A very complete answer. Thank