# Minion pro with LuaLaTeX and XeTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, minionpro

The following code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
  \title{A motif approach to the Mordell conjecture}
  \author{Shurik G.}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

compiles differently with XeTeX:
[image: Correct XeTeX result]
and LuaLaTeX:
[image: Faulty LuaLaTeX result]
Why does LuaLaTeX produce the title in italic?
How can one solve the problem keeping the LuaLaTeX engine?
I checked that LuaLaTeX works correctly with other fonts, including Cambria.
TeXlive 2016 with updates, Linux x86_64.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315452/minion-pro-tl2016-and-lualaex?rq=1

Comment: @Mico: If XeTeX gets it right then it is a luaotfload bug, blaming fonts will not make the issue go away.

Comment: @Mico XeTeX reads all font information from the font files by itself, it relies on the OS only to get a list of installed fonts, so whatever XeTeX does luaotfload can do.

Comment: @KhaledHosny - Many thanks for this clarification -- I retract my earlier comments, actually, I'll delete them right now.