# LuaLateX vs XeLaTex Myriad

Tags: xetex, luatex

When I typeset this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\setsansfont{MyriadPro-BoldSemiCn}
\sffamily
Hello world !

\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\sffamily
{\bfseries Hello world !}
\end{document}
```

the output is different if I use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I think the correct output is the first but I don't know what happens with LuaLaTeX. Any help? Thanks in advanced.

After Mico's comment:

[image: Xelatex output]

[image: Lualatex output]

The first is Xelatex output and the second is lualatex output.

This is the xualatex.log https://www.dropbox.com/s/yarim34cx4thksp/xelatex.log?dl=0

and this is the lualatex.log
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5n3t62vq6pb2jy/lualatex.log?dl=0

Comment: For the benefit of the folks who don't have access to `MyriadPro-BoldSemiCn` on their systems, please (a) post a screenshot of the output produced by LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, respectively and (b) be a bit more explicit about what the issue may be.

Comment: @jpayansomet This seems to be a problem about luaotfload's detection of the bold font which might be caused by some recent changes. Is luaotfload up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, luaotfload is up to date.

Comment: @jpayansomet Could you upload the fontname database (located at `/Users/javierpayansomet/Librar
y/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.lua.gz`)? This file contains information about all installed fonts, if you are not comfortable making it publicly available you also could send it by E-Mail.

Comment: No problem @MarcelKrüger: https://www.dropbox.com/s/95ebjqo34mnvx6h/luaotfload-names.lua.gz?dl=0

Comment: @jpayansomet Thanks. This is a luaotfload bug, we will probably fix it with the next release. Until then, you can probably apply the answers from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315452/minion-pro-tl2016-and-lualatex

Comment: @MarcelKrüger similar problem than with lucida? In any case, as I'm only sometimes reachable this weekend, the next update will probably on tuesday, so there is enough time to add whatever correction is needed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, luaotfload only checks a prefix of the typographicsubfamily, but these fonts only add a suffix for alternative widths, so we get false positives. Anyway, I have to prepare for an exam on Monday, so I will probably only be able to handle this after that.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger then I will wait - it's fine for me gives me more time to test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for your comments. I'll wait for the new release anyway. Happy weekend